# Typo3 PHPUNIT tests with multiple arguments

Tags: phpunit, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm starting with writing some UnitTests for my Extension, now I've got the problem that I got this error:

```
Call to a member function hasArgument() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\typo3conf\ext\rere\Classes\Controller\FachController.php on line 121
```

In Line 121 in FachController is this:

```
if ($this->request->hasArgument('modul')) {
```

I Think the problem is that I don't send the Argument to the controller.

So I tried this:

```
    $fach = new \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Fach();

    $view = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\View\\ViewInterface');
    $view->expects($this->once())->method('assign')->with(array('newFach' => $fach, 'modul' => 1));
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);

    $this->subject->newAction($fach);
```

But that dosn't have any effect ... why?

**Update:**

Dosn't work right now ... tried to add more mocks ... for other elements like findByUid ... but how should the mock look like?

```
 $modul = new \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Modul();

    $mockRequest = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Request');
    $mockRequest->expects($this->once())->method('hasArgument')->with('modul');

    $this->inject($this->subject, 'request', $mockRequest);

    $mockRequest->expects($this->once())->method('findByUid')->with(1);
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'request', $mockRequest);

    $view = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\View\\ViewInterface');
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);
    //$view->expects($this->once())->method('assign')->with('modul', $modul);

    $this->subject->showAction();
```

**Update 3**

Code of New Action got error by getUid()

```
    public function newActionAssignsTheGivenFachToView() {
    $fach = new \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Fach();

    $mockRequest = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Request');
    $mockRequest->expects($this->any())->method('hasArgument')->with('modul');
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'request', $mockRequest);

    $objectmanager = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\ObjectManager', array(), array(), '', FALSE);
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'objectManager', $objectmanager);

    $modulRepository = $this->getMock('ReRe\\Rere\\Domain\\Repository\\ModulRepository');
    $modulRepository->expects($this->any())->method('findByUid')->with(1);
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'modulRepository', $modulRepository);

    $view = $this->getMock(self::VIEWINTERFACE);
    $view->expects($this->any())->method(self::ASSIGN)->with('newFach', $fach);
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);

    $this->subject->newAction($fach);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test fails, because `$this->request` is not known to your unit test for the `newAction`. You need to create a mockObject for the request and inject it in  test for the `newAction` as shown below:

```
$mockRequest = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Request');
$mockRequest->expects($this->once())->method('hasArgument')->with('modul');
$this->inject($this->subject, 'request', $mockRequest);
```

Comment: thanks how can I put mor than one argument? I need to send the fach object and the modul

Comment: I don't really understand why whe mockRequest should expect a "findByUid". It seems you're mixing up things there. FindByUid is a method from a repository, which you also have to inject into your unit test for the action. The full code of the action (showAction or newAction) would be helpful.

Comment: yeah of course I know taht findByUid is from repo but I don't know how to make a mock for it ...

Comment: I've added the new action above

Comment: In my extension [sf_event_mgt](https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt) I have full code coverage for all controller actions. You could take this as an example how to mock the different components in controller unit tests

Comment: do I have to make a mock of my own repository or of the typo3 core functions?

Comment: Yes, create a Mock for your repository. You are "just" unit testing the controller actions and every code from outside that action is not initialized., so you must inject it.

Comment: I've tried it ... but nothing works^^ ... what kind of mock do I need for the getUid() function? Domain/Model/ ?? dosn't work ... `$modul = $this->getMock('ReRe\\Rere\\Domain\\Model\\Modul', array('getUid'), array(), '', FALSE);
        $modul->expects($this->once())->method('getUid')->will($this->returnValue($moduluid));
        $this->inject($this->subject, 'modul', $modul);`

Comment: Frist inject the mock for the request as described - but not with $this->once() but this->any() since you call hasArgument at least twice. Then create an object of type "modul" which at least has the properties you use in the view-assignment. Next create a mockObject for the modulRepository (findByUid) method and return the formerly created "modul" object. Controller unit tests can be a pain because of all dependencies, so I suggest to start with a simple action and extend it step by step (functionality and tests)

Comment: Okay thanks I gonna try this tonights evening. Yeah its a bit strange but your explanations are very helpful! Thabks a lot for this

Comment: I've tried it .. but I have lots of errors again ... can You probably show me how to fix it that I can adapt it to my other Actions?, I've added the code above in Updated 3 block

Comment: You're almost there. Your mock of the moduleRepository should return the modul Object. Try  $modulRepository->expects($this->any())->method('findByUid')->will($this->returnValue($modul));

Comment: Why do you want to unit tests your controllers? I would recommend to make functional tests or behavior tests with Behat instead.